# How to create a "Block device" in Windows

Tags: windows, kernel, block-device

For those familiar with Linux, it is possible to create a module and register it as a block device. This allows the user to mount it as a regular disk (while all the block I/O is handled by the module, e.g. USB mass storage).

Is there a way to do this in Windows ? (Need to create a volume mountable by Windows. The raw data will come from propriety interface).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (and it's not easy!) is to write a [Storport Miniport driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms803198.aspx), you can even do this with KMDF as well. The latest issue of OSR's "The NT Insider" has an article on how to do this, but it's *not* going to be any kind of easy.

You will learn a ton though, so if you're interested in kernel development, this is a good way to get started!

Answer (score 2):

You can find some simple block device drivers at http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/ . Look at the FileDisk driver, which is a Windows equivalent of /dev/loop

Comment: I think the HttpDisk driver on the same page is an even better fit if you want to create a block device whose contents are generated programmatically somehow (rather than coming from an existing file).  I was very impressed to see that in 2018 on Windows 10, after following the simple installation instructions, the example command line, which mounts an .iso provided by a Microsoft webserver as a local disk, just worked!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Truecrypt](http://truecrypt.org/) project. They have a pretty good implementation of a virtual block device.